# How to export a graph with alternative text in Excel to PDF using Python or R?

Tags: python, r, excel, vba, pdf

I have about 500 graphs generated in Excel using VBA and I need to export them to pdf. These graphs have alternative text to make them accessible for blind people. When I use the VBA (ExportAsFixedFormat) to generate the pdf, the alternative text will be missed in the pdf. Is there a code in python or R to convert the graph from excel to pdf and retain the alternative text?

If I manually save the graphs as pdf, the alternative text will be saved with the graph in pdf file. However, since I have too many graphs, it would be good to be able to do this automatically.

```
 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFileName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

The above code in VBA is helpful for creating pdf but does not keep the alternative text.

Comment: What happens if you switch on the macro recorder whilst saving, is the generated code what you have supplied?

Comment: "If I manually save the graphs as pdf" - exactly how are you doing this?

Comment: You can copy/pastespecial the chart as a picture on the sheet, then set the alt text on the picture to the same as the chart.  Then delete the chart.  You can do this on a copy of your workbook if you need to keep the charts.  The alt text on the chart pictures will carry over to the PDF.

Comment: ...I guess I was assuming embedded charts.  Are you using chart sheets?

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1062228/how-to-attach-alternate-text-to-powerpoint-art-exported-to-pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code generates a pdf file for each `Sheet` (excluding any `Worksheet`) in `ThisWorkbook`:

```vb
Sub Charts_Export()
Const kPath As String = "D:\@D_Trash\SO Questions\Output\#Name.pdf"    'Update as required
Dim oSht As Object, sPath As String
    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each oSht In .Sheets
            With oSht
                If oSht.Type <> xlWorksheet Then
                    sPath = Replace(kPath, "#Name", .Name)    'Update as required
                    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
                        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                        Filename:=sPath, _
                        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End If: End With: Next: End With

    End Sub
```

*Once the pdf files are open, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> simultaneously to activate the `Read Out Loud` option in pdf. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> simultaneously to read the `AlternativeText`.*

[image]

The previous code, which uses the same piece published by the OP, exported the Charts as pdf files, including the `Alternative text` in each.

This seems to indicate that the problem could be due to the method used to add the `AlternativeText` to the `Chart`. I could not find a method to add the `AlternativeText` to a `Chart` once it has been moved as a `Sheet`, so the `AlternativeText` has to be added before moving the `Chart` to a `Sheet`, when the `Chart` is still an object (`Shape`) in a worksheet.

Use this method to add the `AlternativeText` to each `Chart` before moving it to a Sheet`.

```vb
Private Sub Charts_Add_AlternativeText()
Const kAltTxt As String = "This is a test of the Alt Text in graph [#Name]"    'Update as required
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim co As ChartObject

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")    'Update as required
    For Each co In ws.ChartObjects
        co.ShapeRange.AlternativeText = Replace(kAltTxt, "#Name", co.Name)    'Update as required
    Next

    End Sub
```

Or use this method to add the `AlternativeText` to each `Chart` sheet.

```vb
Private Sub Charts_Add_AlternativeText()
Const kWsName As String = "!Temp"
Const kAltTxt As String = "This is a test of the Alt Text in graph [#Name]"     'Update as required
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim oSht As Object, sp As Shape
Dim sChName As String, bIdx As Byte

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    With wb

        Rem Add Temp Worksheet
        On Error Resume Next
        .Worksheets(kWsName).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set ws = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = kWsName

        Rem Work with Chart Sheets
        For Each oSht In .Sheets
            With oSht
                If oSht.Type <> xlWorksheet Then

                    Rem Move Chart to Temp Worksheet
                    bIdx = .Index
                    sChName = .Name
                    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=kWsName

                    Set sp = ws.Shapes(1)
                    With sp

                        Rem Add AlternativeText to Shape (Chart)
                        .AlternativeText = Replace(kAltTxt, "#Name", sChName)    'Update as required

                        Rem Move Chart to Chart Sheet
                        .Chart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:=sChName
                        wb.Sheets(sChName).Move Before:=wb.Sheets(bIdx)

    End With: End If: End With: Next: End With

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Great answer! I hope OP could make it work. Thanks!